# FileImporter missing Select option

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swiftui-fileimporter

This is driving me crazy for many days now. I am trying to use the `.fileImport()` modifier in SwiftUI and apparently I am missing something VERY obvious but for the life of me I cannot find a way to have the "Select" option (see screenshots.

This is like the simplest it can get:

```
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

struct DocImporterView: View {
   // @Binding var document: ProofOfBugDocument

    @State var isPicking: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Pick") {
            isPicking.toggle()
        }
        .fileImporter(
            isPresented: $isPicking,
            allowedContentTypes: [.item, .folder, .directory],
            allowsMultipleSelection: true, //this btw does not enable the select. Instead just starts the Document Picker in selection mode (but folders cannot be selected)
            onCompletion: { result in
                print("Picked: \(result)")
            })
    }
}

struct DocImporterView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DocImporterView()//(document: .constant(ProofOfBugDocument()))
    }
}
```

Any ideas/help appreciated

[image]
[image]